# Which browser has most similar engine to iPad WebKit? (SVG, CSS)

Tags: ios, html, browser, safari, webkit

I need to check rendering of a large sum of HTML5 "widgets" that will be shown in an iPad WebKit. Which desktop browser gives me the most similar renering experience? My widgets mostly consist of SVGs positioned with CSS3 and some CSS masking.

Is it Safari on a Mac?

EDIT: The desktop OS is not a concern, I can pick whatever I want for this...

EDIT: What particularly interrests me is if desktop Safari is closer to iOS Safari than Chrome is. They are both based on WebKit, but I see a lot of tiny rendering differences between Chrome and iOS Safari.

Answer (score 2):

How about mobile Safari on the iPad Simulator?

Unfortunately, the iPad Simulator is Mac-only.  If you can't test on that, Apple recommends using Safari and changing your user agent string to the iPad's user agent string.  You can find instructions from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html).

Comment: Is it exact like on the iOS? (I'm on Windows). Thanks for answering.

Comment: I can swith to Mac, no problem. The point for me is that for example Chrome is also WebKit, but the amount of tiny differences and bugs is driving me crazy...

Comment: My guess is that iPad Simulator Mobile Safari is better than Safari, which is better than Chrome.

Comment: But there is no replacement for actually testing on the real device.

Answer (score 0):

Try real Safari. It uses Webkit and since you're on windows, you can't download the iPad simulator.

Comment: Is desktop Safari is closer to iOS Safari than Chrome is. They are both based on WebKit, but I see a lot of tiny rendering differences between Chrome and iOS Safari.

Comment: If you can switch to mac and download the ipad simulator (http://developer.apple.com/ios) then do that. If not, I would use Safari. Especially if you use the developer setting in Safari it will allow you to easily change your user agent to and iPad. the ios Safari and desktop Safari are much more alike then Chrome and ios Safari.

Answer (score 0):

On the desktop, anything that uses WebKit is going to give you a similar rendering experience especially with regards to more technical things like SVGs.  Unfortunately, there are still browser-specific quirks that you won't be able to notice without actually testing it on either the simulator or a real device.